# How to draw a line from the centroid of a contour to the perimeter of the contour?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm obtaining the centroid of a contour using moments like so:

```
cnt = np.vstack([cnt[0]]).squeeze()
M = cv2.moments(cnt)
cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
```

I want to divide the contour into 4 quadrants, so that would require two lines to be drawn, one vertical and one horizontal, both passing through the obtained centroid. How do I go about doing it?

Comment: If the contour is convex, it should be relatively straightforward. Iterate through the line segments defined by the points in the contour. Find the intersects with `y=cx` and `x=cy` (should be 2 each). Plot the lines. If it's concave, you might get more than two intersections, so you have to select the two most distant for each axis.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to obtain all the coordinates of the contour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this looks like a task for OpenCV, you may want to have a look at the Shapely package:

http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html

Shapely allows you to calculate intersections between polygons, and so the solution gets quite simple: For both the horizontal and the vertical line running through the centroid of your contour, you just calculate the intersections with the contour and draw lines to those intersections.

Lacking your  original figure, I have used an ellipse to demonstrate the solution. Since you said that you have only some sample points of your contour, I have used a "coarse" ellipse which is just approximated by a few points.

Output looks like this, hope that this is what you were looking for:

[image]

Source code is lengthy due to all the visualization, but hopefully self-explaining:

```
import shapely.geometry as shapgeo
import numpy as np
import cv2

def make_image():
    img = np.zeros((500, 500), np.uint8)
    white = 255
    cv2.ellipse( img, (250, 300), (100,70), 30, 0, 360, white, -1 )
    return img


if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = make_image()

    #Create a "coarse" ellipse 
    _, contours0, hierarchy = cv2.findContours( img.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = [cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 3, True) for cnt in contours0]
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    vis = np.zeros((h, w, 3), np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours( vis, contours, -1, (128,255,255), 1)

    #Extract contour of ellipse
    cnt = np.vstack([contours[0]]).squeeze()

    #Determine centroid
    M = cv2.moments(cnt)
    cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
    cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
    print cx, cy

    #Draw full segment lines 
    cv2.line(vis,(cx,0),(cx,w),(150,0,0),1)
    cv2.line(vis,(0,cy),(h,cy),(150,0,0),1)


    # Calculate intersections using Shapely
    # http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html
    PolygonEllipse= shapgeo.asLineString(cnt)
    PolygonVerticalLine=shapgeo.LineString([(cx,0),(cx,w)])
    PolygonHorizontalLine=shapgeo.LineString([(0,cy),(h,cy)])

    insecv= np.array(PolygonEllipse.intersection(PolygonVerticalLine)).astype(np.int)
    insech= np.array(PolygonEllipse.intersection(PolygonHorizontalLine)).astype(np.int)
    cv2.line(vis,(insecv[0,0], insecv[0,1]),(insecv[1,0], insecv[1,1]),(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.line(vis,(insech[0,0], insech[0,1]),(insech[1,0], insech[1,1]),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('contours', vis)

    0xFF & cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```