# Python Numpy arctan2 asterisk and .T meaning

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to understand Python numpy arctan definition.

What does the

1. asterisk after arctan2 represent?
2. and what does .T mean?

Below we are finding the angles between a set of contour points and a center.

Just trying to understand these syntax.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html

```
angles = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(*(np.tile(center, (len(pts), 1)) - pts).T))
```

Comment: The asterisk expands the list of arguments (arctan2 takes two arguments). `.T` transposes its instance.

Comment: `*` is for unpacking multiple arguments. `.T` is for transposing.

Comment: interesting, feel free to post as answer, where did you receive the documentation for expanding/unpacking? I didnt see it in resource, appreciate it ! cc @00

Comment: cc @MayankPorwal

Comment: One learns that over time. It is a reasonably common Python idiom, albeit not always the most clearest.

Comment: The transpose is numpy specific, the argument expansion is basic python syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through:

1. [`Asteriks in Python`](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/) to understand how the unpacking of args happen.
2. [`numpy.Transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html)

Comment: ok, asterisk is kind of like spread operator in typescript/javascript?

Comment: its making this into a wider expansive list? it seems *(np.tile(center, (len(pts), 1)) - pts)

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess as to what `pts` and `center` might look like:

```
In [322]: pts = np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1]])
In [323]: center = np.array([.5,.5])
```

The inner part of the expression is then:

```
In [324]: np.tile(center, (len(pts), 1)) - pts
Out[324]: 
array([[ 0.5,  0.5],
       [-0.5, -0.5],
       [-0.5, -1.5],
       [-1.5, -0.5]])
```

Taking the transpose, and unpacking:

```
In [325]: x, y = (np.tile(center, (len(pts), 1)) - pts).T
In [326]: x
Out[326]: array([ 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -1.5])
In [327]: y
Out[327]: array([ 0.5, -0.5, -1.5, -0.5])
```

So the full expression is:

```
In [328]: np.arctan2(*(np.tile(center, (len(pts), 1)) - pts).T)
Out[328]: array([ 0.78539816, -2.35619449, -2.8198421 , -1.89254688])
```

and the same as:

```
In [329]: np.arctan2(x,y)
Out[329]: array([ 0.78539816, -2.35619449, -2.8198421 , -1.89254688])
```

But we don't need `tile` to subtract the `pts` from `center`:

```
In [333]: center-pts
Out[333]: 
array([[ 0.5,  0.5],
       [-0.5, -0.5],
       [-0.5, -1.5],
       [-1.5, -0.5]])
```

`center` is (2,) shape, `pts` is (n,2); by broadcasting they subtract.

So perhaps a clearer way of writing this is:

```
In [341]: temp = center-pts
In [343]: np.arctan2(temp[:,0],temp[:,1])
Out[343]: array([ 0.78539816, -2.35619449, -2.8198421 , -1.89254688])
```

Comment: feel free to place an edit request in the answer, if you believe so, appreciate it https://stackoverflow.com/a/66904873/15435022